# ADDING CLOSE BRACE ON ARCMAP 10.5

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

[image]

How do I add the close brace as shown in the image above?

I'm using ArcMap 10.5

Comment: Please do not use ALL CAPS in your titles.  They are a downvote magnet.

Answer (score 2):

When looking at your screenshot one can see the line and the curly bracket are not connecting nicely. I suppose the curly bracket was added using Insert -> Text -> '{' and then adjusting the position and angle.